# React Datepicker - No puedo volver al primer mes luego de moverme a los siguientes

Tags: reactjs, datepicker

Estoy haciendo un datepicker usando esta libreria: https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker/

El problema es el siguiente: Al montarse el calendar, hay fechas habilitadas y fechas deshabilitadas.

En la mayoria de los casos las fechas habilitadas comienzan en abril.

Entonces al abrir el calendario (estoy mostrando dos meses) veo febrero (mes en curso) y marzo. En ninguno tengo fechas habilitadas para su seleccion entonces navego al siguiente mes que es abril.

Ahora veo Marzo y Abril, el primero no tiene fechas disponibles, y ya no me deja volver atras y ver febrero **(este es el problema)**.

Si paso un mes hacia adelante, ahora veo Abril y Mayo. Ambos tienen fechas seleccionables, pero no puedo volver al mes anterior.

Si ahora paso a ver Mayo y Junio, sí puedo volver hacia Abril, supongo que porque Abril tiene fechas disponibles.

Intenté usar `minDate={new Date()}` pero el comportamiento es el mismo.

No importa si uso `minDate={new Date()}`, el resultado es el mismo

```
  <DatePicker
    disabledKeyboardNavigation
    inline
    selectsDisabledDaysInRange
    selectsRange
    showDisabledMonthNavigation
    endDate={endDate}
    highlightDates={includeDates}
    includeDates={includeDates}
    minDate={new Date()}
    monthsShown={2}
    renderDayContents={renderDayContents}
    selected={startDate}
    startDate={startDate}
    onChange={onChange}
  />
```

Alguien sabe como puedo hacer navegables los meses a partir de hoy (`new Date()`)? Sin importar si tiene dias `disabled` o no?